# My question has been mistakenly marked duplicate

Tags: support, reopen-request, exact-duplicates

My question here - https://superuser.com/questions/725545/ - has been marked duplicate to this question - [Does installing many programs really slow down Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/180424/).

To those who say its duplicate, the other question is oriented towards slowing down of the computer and the OP of the question is also testing software and will remove them later. I had seen that question earlier and it did not help me. I am using softwares that I will always need but many of them will be used less often. Like CS6 Master Collection, Lightwave 3d, Maya, 3Ds Max etc.

I am asking will there be any other issues that I might be overlooking now and then they would cause problem. I don't like to reinstall my Windows.

I raised a ticket (no. 201403071002288671) and got the following reply:

> Hi,
>
> I'm sympathetic to your situation but I'm afraid it's not my place to overturn community decision. To argue in support of reopening your question, please head to Meta Super User and begin a discussion question on the subject of your post. Indicate what it is that the existing question covers, what your question is meant to cover, and why your question is insufficiently addressed by the existing question. The more solid material you place, similar to what you've written here, but as much as you can, that will put you on the road to reopening.
>
> The Stack Exchange Team

Kindly remove the duplicate mark on it.

Comment: You're a hobbyist with licenses to master collection and 3 major 3d design packages?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg When you buy softwares like these, you get two licenses; one for a desktop and another for a laptop. A friend of mine doesn't use his desktop apps so I use them (at very cheap!)

Comment: Even if the question wasn't a duplicate the question quality still is lacking.  I would work on that problem before asking the community to reverse their decision

Comment: @Ramhound Can you please explain in detail what quality was lacking. I will see to it next time. Regards...

Comment: @AwalGarg - The biggest problem is your question isn't really clear.  You didn't clarify what you meant by "harm" the computer.  The original question also has some major grammar problem.  Your current core question minus your "edits" would be closed because it wasn't clear what your question was even if it wasn't a duplicate ( which it is )

Comment: @Ramhound I am sorry, I can't identify any grammar problems. And I do not think questions are closed for grammar problems. The answer I have accepted is all that I want. I think that guy (ultrasawblade) identified what I meant. The question was over there. But I what I am trying to say is, that it is different from the _other_ question, because, the _other_ question's OP is **testing** software which he does not trust until now. If he finds them useful, he will keep them, and if not, then he will uninstall them. I am using trusted and useful software. I am sorry, I can't explain any further...

Comment: It wasn't different the answer in how to test software is the same as keeping software installed.  Questions that have to many problems and are not clear because is grammar problems are closed.  You wanted to know the problems I saw so I shared.